# PHP set cookie not saving valid data

Tags: php, cookies

I'm having a problem with a form that presents different options depending on whether its a user's first, second, or third visit. The first time I test this the cookie data is all valid (although with "+" symbols between words and "%20" in lieu of the @ symbol in an email address). However as soon as I visit the page the 2nd time the setcookie saves only `; ?>` in the cookie. The email generated returns that same "; ?>" data where the field data should be. I don't understand why it's changing the cookie like that..?

```
if (isset($_POST["firstname"])) {
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
} 
else {
if (isset($_COOKIE["modvisitor_fn"])) {
    $firstname = $_COOKIE["modvisitor_fn"];
}
}
if (isset($_POST["lastname"])) {
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
} 
else {
if (isset($_COOKIE["modvisitor_ln"])) {
    $lastname = $_COOKIE["modvisitor_ln"];
}
}
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
$email = $_POST["email"];
} 
else {
if (isset($_COOKIE["modvisitor_e"])) {
$email = $_COOKIE["modvisitor_e"];
}
}

// Set a cookie with visitor information
$date_of_expiry = time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie( "modvisitor_fn", $firstname, $date_of_expiry );
setcookie( "modvisitor_ln", $lastname, $date_of_expiry );
setcookie( "modvisitor_e", $email, $date_of_expiry );
```

FYI the reason I set the cookie is because the 2nd time they visit they don't have to fill out the same info in our form, they are only asked for their title and company.

Comment: It seems like the end of a php statement from an html form. Have you checked the contents of POST when it sets the odd data

Comment: Interesting. In this case the form only supplied a couple of items, and the other data elements should have been loaded from cookies. When I print_r the POST variables I get this:
"Array ( [email] => ; ?> [company] => ; ?> [firstname] => ; ?> [lastname] => ; ?> [title] => ; ?> [comments] => [visitnum] => 3 [req] => tool [Completed] => Completed )"
If data was not submitted via POST then I expected those items to show as null ('')..???

Comment: I found the problem! It's not the cookies, but the POST variables carried over from the previous form's "hidden" fields (which was read from the cookies). I cleaned up the \" errors and the data now feeds through correctly. Thank you xd6 for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

when setting cookie, they must be sent along with other headers, **before** any content (such as html, or even a whitespace).

be sure to put your `setcookie()` before any other code which may output something to your page.

oh and rtm :)

Comment: that does not explain the unusual contents of the cookie

Comment: from the fact that the cookie is storing what looks like a ending line semicolon and a php closing tag `; ?>`, yep, it pretty much explain which characters were stored instead of desired content, eg the last characters sent to the browser

Comment: All PHP is before any HTML. Yes, I did RTFM, my code matches the format, and I'm getting weird output. My cookies look good in the Chrome settings -- email shows as myname%40mydomain.com. However the form contents that I email outputs the strange characters.

`$message = "FROM $firstname $lastname ($email) requested..." ;`

My email comes in showing "FROM ; ?> ; ?> (; ?>) ..."